# Deactivating needless properties in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

We have three properties on my animal model:

1. dog_name
2. cat_name
3. monkey_name

One of them must be filled (no more! animal is a dog, a cat or a monkey) and if I set for example cat_name, I want dog_name and monkey_name to be deactivated (user shouldn't set more than one name).

**Is it possible to set this in django admin?**
This example is maybe stupid, but I tried to explain my intensions - deactivating needless properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to avoid a db schema that involves redundant fields if at all possible. Consider a separate "animal type" table with a fkey in your animal table.

So:

animal_type:

```
id       type_name
1        cat
2        dog
3        monkey
```

animal:

```
id       name          type
1        kitty         1
2        fido          2
3        rover         2
4        mr banannas   3
```

etc, will save you pain in the long run

edit: to answer your further comment below, you could try overriding the clean() function of your model, so

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    first_property = models.FileField()
    second_property = models.ImageField()

    def clean(self)
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        if self.first_property.name not in ['', None] and \
           self.second_property.name not in ['', None]:
            raise ValidationError('Cannot have a first_property and a second_property!.')
```

This will throw up an error message whenever you try to save the model, though it won't stop them from actually entering those two values in the form.

Comment: My example was very simple - but what if I had two properties: first_property (ImageField) and second_property (FileField) - this solution wouldn't work. Properties won't be of the same type such as in this simple example. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what you want you can create [Model Proxies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#proxy-models), register them with Django admin and deactivate needless fields using `exclude`, `fields` or `fieldsets` attribute in admin model.

```
# models.py

class Animal(models.Model):
    dog_name = models.CharField()
    cat_name = models.CharField()
    monkey_name = models.CharField()

class Dog(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Cat(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Monkey(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

# admin.py

class DogAdmin(models.Model):
    exclude = ['cat_name', 'monkey_name']

class CatAdmin(models.Model):
    fields = ['cat_name', 'other_field']

class MonkeyAdmin(models.Model):
    exclude = ['cat_name', 'monkey_name']

admin.site.register(Dog, DogAdmin)
admin.site.register(Cat, CatAdmin)
admin.site.register(Monkey, MonkeyAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is by adding javascript that disable the "other" fields when you set one. You can then enforce this in the form/model validation.

But I should say that I think the best way to deal with this, if it can be applied to your problem, is the way PT114 propose.

Answer (score 0):

If the different animals represent different things stored in the database, then you might just want to create seperate Model objects with their own tables, and link them together using [GenericForignKeys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey).

This adds all sorts of complications, but django is better at common things than unusual things, and the way it seems you want to store information (which is actually quite common IMHO) is difficult with traditional relational databases.